# Bootstrap table cell with float and dynamic side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've spent the last few days to get my bootstrap table to look like I want.

I just can not get it to work.

What I want is that the first td has to be dynamic width, with a max width and min width because the value is between 1 and 9999. The number must be right aligned. The minus button should be left aligned. And all this have to be on the same line.

The middle cell must also have dynamic width. but with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which I also got to work. The last td has fixed width.

Here is some example of what i want.

Dynamic side of first td and collapsing in second:
[image: dynamic side of first td]
[image: dynamic side of first td]
[image: collapsing in second td]

I have tried many things. Eg. I have tried to make a "clearfix" with fixed width equals with the minus button at the end of the cell. It works only if the value in the cell is 9999 and not 1.

Here is a image of how it looks now:
[image: screenshot now]

Here a bootply of it: http://www.bootply.com/jNx2MJrNG0

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .cartTable thead {
            color: #333;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border-color: #ddd;
        }

        .cartTable th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .cartTable > tbody > tr > td {
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .cartTable th:first-child,
        .cartTable td:first-child {
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .cartTable .quantityColumn {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 10px;
            min-width: 59px;
            max-width: 114px;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 8px 0;
        }
        /*.minusDiv {
            clear: both;
        }*/
        .quantityColumn .minusToLeft {
            /*display: inline-block;*/
            /*text-align: right;*/
            float: left;
        }

        .minusToRight {
            width: 40px;
            display: inline-block;
            clear: both;
        }

        .quantityColumn .btnMinus {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .quantityColumn .btnPlus {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .quantityColumnDiv {
            min-width: 59px;
            max-width: 114px;
        }

        .cartTable .nameColumn {
            max-width: 80px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .cartTable .btnColumn {
            width: 105px;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 15px;
            /*text-align: right;*/
        }

        @media (max-width:767px) {
            .cartTable .quantityColumn {
                padding: 8px;
            }

            .cartTable .btnColumn {
                width: 50px;
            }
        }

        .btnSearch {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <table class="table cartTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="quantityColumn">
                                    <span class="minusToLeft">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs hidden-xs btnMinus">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                    1
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs hidden-xs btnPlus">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td class="nameColumn">ALongTextToCollaps</td>
                                <td class="btnColumn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnSearch">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="quantityColumn">

                                    <span class="minusToLeft">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs hidden-xs btnMinus">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>

                                    9999
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs hidden-xs btnPlus">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                    </button>

                                </td>
                                <td class="nameColumn">test cake</td>
                                <td class="btnColumn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btnSearch">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How does I get the first td's content to stay on the same line, with the minus button to left, so the numbers is right aligned over each other and the column still will be dynamic in width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Increasing the `width` in `.cartTable quantityColumn` to 120px (or just adjust it to the maximum size of the quantity column) to give it some more space
- What i prefer is having another two columns, one for the **-** and one for the **+**

Comment: The first solution will make the td fixed width, so if all values is 1, the td will be to big.

Comment: The second solution did i tried, i also like that solution. But the buttons have to be hidden in small screens. So I have to make 2 different `th`, one with colspan and class `.hidden-xs`. And one without colspan and class `visible-xs`. That solutions gives a warning (A table row was 5 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row) in the HTML validator, which the website preferably should not.

Comment: As for the first solution, a column will always have a fixed width since it wont be bigger for more content and smaller for less content in the same column. what you could do is place the text in the center of the `<td>`s so it won't look weird

Comment: As for the second solution, why does the first `<th>` needs to be hidden? i think that add two normal blank `<th>`s would do the job, one before the quantity and one after it, let me know what you think

Comment: I've spent a little time working with solution 2 and ended up with the following solution, which works as it should and it is valid html.
`<th>
  <div style="width: 10px;">Antal</div>
</th>
<th class="hidden-xs"></th>
<th class="hidden-xs"></th>`

Comment: Glad my solution was helpful and got you in the right direction :) Please do accept and upvote the answer for the future people to come